# Analytical rotation - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: geometry

After drawing a 90º rotation by hand and analysing the changes in each $x$ and $y$ coordinate, I deduced that the algorithm for a rotation around a centre $C:(x,y)$ was $P:(x_+\Delta x,\  y+\Delta y) \to P':(x-\Delta y,\ y+\Delta x)$. Therefore, if $C:(0,0) \Rightarrow P:(x,y) \to P':(-y,x)$.  However, now I'm trying to do an exercise and the resulting triangle is clearly not congruent to the original:

[image]

I suppose there's something wrong with the algorithm because I've checked the coordinates several times and couldn't find any mistakes. Can anyone tell me why it isn't working?

**EDIT:** OK, so I had made the dumbest mistake ever and placed $(-1,-2)$ at $(-1,2)$ not one, not two, but *three times*. I should clearly set some caffeine-in-bloodstream lower bound for doing these things. Thanks to @Max for actually pointing it out! (if you want rep just answer and I'll mark it as accepted).

[image]

Comment: I believe you wanted $(-2,1) \to (-1,-2)$.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I can't believe I couldn't spot it!

Comment: By the way, you can post it as an answer if you want rep :)